# Order by created_at date Django

Tags: django, django-models

Im trying to order the 'records' in this model by their creation date/time, but am running into issues.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):     
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  class Meta:
    order_with_respect_to = 'created_at'
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run syncdb

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to'
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what `order_with_respect_to` is for - it's for marking a model as ordered with regard to a related model. Personally, I've never had an occasion to use it so I can't really speak from experience about it - except to say that it's not how you do a simple date ordering.

To order by creation time, use the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) `meta` attribute instead:

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['created_at']
```

In strict point of fact, you don't absolutely have to declare this. If you don't declare any other ordering, either on your model or your query, results will be sorted by their PK. And by default, PKs will be an auto-incrementing series so objects will be implicitly sorted by their creation order. But if you actually care about the sort order, it's best to be explicit rather than rely on that side effect of ascending PKs.